# The Dotnet core binary linked to Mono C# application on the Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, mono, ubuntu-14.04

Have dotnet core sample library project on Linux. Build it & generate DLL on Linux.

Want to link the dotnet core generated DLL functionality on Mono C# application on Linux.

Please let me know, How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not very understandable, please revise it

Comment: I am clearly mentioned, want to use the dot core library in mono c# on the Linux Platform. The dot core is available on multiple Platform (Windows, Linux & Mac). I want to reuse the code of the dot net core DLL. I want to use mono c# on the Linux. that why want to link the dot core functionality to mono c#.

Comment: If that's your true question, then it is impossible. Different class libraries have their compatible platforms, and .NET Core/Mono cannot be mixed, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff